# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a custom 'Matrix' class in C++ and have run into an "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" error that I cannot understand. My relevant code is-

**HEADER**

```
#ifndef CORE_H
#define CORE_H
#include <stdint.h>

class Size
{
public:
    Size(const uint64_t nrows, const uint64_t ncols, const uint64_t nframes);

    uint64_t rows;
    uint64_t cols;
    uint64_t frames;
};

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(const uint64_t rows, const uint64_t cols, const uint64_t frames);
    Matrix(const uint64_t rows, const uint64_t cols, const uint64_t frames, T *data);

    void print();

private:
    Size sz;
    T *_data;
};

#endif //CORE_H
```

**SOURCE**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "core.h"

Size::Size(const uint64_t nrows, const uint64_t ncols, const uint64_t nframes)
{
    rows = nrows;
    cols = ncols;
    frames = nframes;
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const uint64_t rows, const uint64_t cols, const uint64_t frames)
{
    Matrix<T>(rows, cols, frames, malloc(rows * cols * frames * sizeof(T)));
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const uint64_t rows, const uint64_t cols, const uint64_t frames, T *data)
{
    sz = Size(rows, cols, frames);
    _data = data;
}

template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::print()
{
    printf("[");
    for (uint64_t f = 0; f < sz.frames; f++) {
        printf("[");
        for (uint64_t r = 0; r < sz.rows; r++) {
            for (uint64_t c = 0; c < sz.cols; c++) {
                printf("%.3f,", element(r, c, f));
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

**TEST**

```
#include "core.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    Matrix<int> mat(2, 2, 2, data);
    mat.print();
    return 0;
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Matrix<int>::print()", referenced from:
      _main in rand.cpp.o
  "Matrix<int>::Matrix(int, int, int, int*)", referenced from:
      _main in rand.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [examples/rand] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/rand.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm sure it is something small but I can't figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you added the source file to your project? Including `"core.h"` allows the compiler to understand these symbols, adding "core.cpp" allows the linker to link them (after the compiler has compiled them into object code).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template functions (including member functions of template classes) need to be implemented in a header file so their definitions (not just declarations) are visible in all translation units where they might be used.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021) for more information.

Move the definitions of your constructor and `print` functions into your header file, below the definition of the `Matrix` class template.

Comment: I fixed it by adding template class Matrix<type> definitions to the bottom of my .cpp file as per the linked question. Thanks!